# Else if statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

This is what the program wants me to output

Give a number: 10
Give another number: 11
One of the numbers is even.

Give a number: 12
Give another number: 20
Both numbers are even.

Give a number: 15
Give another number: 21
Both numbers are odd.

Here is what I tried to do

```
number1 = int(input("Give a number:"))
number2 = int(input("Give another number:"))
if (number1 % 2 == 0) or (number2 % 2 ==0):
        print("One of the numbers is even.")
elif (number1 % 2 != 0) or (number2 % 2 !=0):
            print("One of the numbers is odd)
```

But the program said I have a syntax error
*Edit: I tried programming this but it doesn't give out the output I want

Comment: Please provide the full error message, it will likely tell you exactly where the problem is

Answer (score 2):

You forgot one `"` at the last print ;)

```
number1 = int(input("Give a number:"))
number2 = int(input("Give another number:"))
if (number1 % 2 == 0) or (number2 % 2 ==0):
        print("One of the numbers is even.")
elif (number1 % 2 != 0) or (number2 % 2 !=0):
            print("One of the numbers is odd")
```

input: `1 & 10`
output: `One of the numbers is even.`

Answer (score 1):

There is a " missing in your last print statement.

It should be: print("One of the numbers is odd")